# How to call my own callback when the user presses "Close" button on Firefox SDK's notifications

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Is there any way to call my own callback when the user presses "Close" button on Firefox SDK's [notifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/notifications)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way since SDK [does not accept](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/addon-sdk/source/lib/sdk/notifications.js#77) `onClose`.

You could create it [yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34587239/2445882) with [nsIAlertsService](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIAlertsService) but that needs `require('chrome')`